# Drools says features require source level of 1.5 or greater even though Java 8 is being used

Tags: java, eclipse, drools

I am following along with the Drools tutorial [here](https://nheron.gitbooks.io/droolsonboarding/content/). Everything seems to be working as expected until I used the for each loop in the [third lesson](https://nheron.gitbooks.io/droolsonboarding/content/gettingStarted/lesson_3.html) where collect is demonstrated:

```
rule "More then 2 CashFlow Line"
    when
        $c : Account( $acc : accountNo )
        $p : AccountingPeriod ($sDate : startDate ,$eDate : endDate )
        $number : ArrayList(size >= 2 )
              from collect( CashFlow( mvtDate >= $sDate && mvtDate  <= $eDate,accountNo == $acc ) )

    then
        showResult.showText("Found more than 2 CashFlow Lines");
        showResult.showText("<<<<<<<<<<");
        for (Object ff : $number){
            showResult.showText(ff.toString());
        }
        showResult.showText(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
end
```

The JUnit tests fail this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating KieBase[Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=lesson3.drl, line=43, column=0
 text=Rule Compilation error Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater]]
```

I have checked both my build path and my compiler complicance level both being 1.8

JRE:
[image: Showing JRE set to 1.8]

Compiler: 
[image: Showing Compiler Compliance set to 1.8]

To be sure I tested with the following code in the same project, it runs as expected.

```
package droolscours;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] testValues = new int[]{1, 2, 3};

        for(int value : testValues){
            System.out.println("Number: " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

I have found similar issues but they relate to the use of older versions of Drools (I am using 6.5.0) or incompatibilities with older versions of WildFly(Which I am not using at all).

I am using Eclipse Neon 4.6.1. 
Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: Indeed, 6.x handles this loop correctly. So I'll have to delete my answer - sorry about that. - Try compiling from the command line, passing all essential Drools jars in the class path, to exclude all doubts about the Java compiler that is used by Eclipse.

Comment: If you running JUnit test inside Eclipse, then Eclipse would have created a Run configuration for that JUnit run, check the jre/jdk version in that Run configuration